# Trying to make a 3dplot

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm trying to make 3d plot. Unfortunately, I can't succeed in getting the desired figure, as shown below.

Here is the figure, where it's a sphere have a charge of -1 inside. And coordinate axes are supposed to be blur inside the sphere may not be dashed.
[image]
Still a MWE:

```
%% Copyright 2009 Jeffrey D. Hein
%
% This work may be distributed and/or modified under the
% conditions of the LaTeX Project Public License, either version 1.3
% of this license or (at your option) any later version.
% The latest version of this license is in
%   http://www.latex-project.org/lppl.txt
% and version 1.3 or later is part of all distributions of LaTeX
% version 2005/12/01 or later.
%
% This work has the LPPL maintenance status `maintained'.
% 
% The Current Maintainer of this work is Jeffrey D. Hein.
%
% This work consists of the files 3dplot.sty and 3dplot.tex

%Description
%-----------
%3dplot.tex - an example file demonstrating the use of the 3dplot.sty package.

%Created 2009-11-07 by Jeff Hein.  Last updated: 2009-11-09
%----------------------------------------------------------

%Update Notes
%------------

%2009-11-07: Created file along with 3dplot.sty package


\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}   %TikZ is required for this to work.  Make sure this exists before the next line

\usepackage{3dplot} %requires 3dplot.sty to be in same directory, or in your LaTeX installation

\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}  %generates a tightly fitting border around the work
\PreviewEnvironment{tikzpicture}
\setlength\PreviewBorder{2mm}

\begin{document}

    %Angle Definitions
    %-----------------

    %set the plot display orientation
    %synatax: \tdplotsetdisplay{\theta_d}{\phi_d}
    \tdplotsetmaincoords{45}{135}

    %define polar coordinates for some vector
    %TODO: look into using 3d spherical coordinate system
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\rvec}{.8}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\thetavec}{45}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\phivec}{60}

    %start tikz picture, and use the tdplot_main_coords style to implement the display 
    %coordinate transformation provided by 3dplot
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=5,tdplot_main_coords]

    % Teken eerst de bol
    \shade[tdplot_screen_coords,ball color = white] (0,0) circle (\rvec);

    %set up some coordinates 
    %-----------------------
    \coordinate (O) at (0,0,0);

    %determine a coordinate (P) using (r,\theta,\phi) coordinates.  This command
    %also determines (Pxy), (Pxz), and (Pyz): the xy-, xz-, and yz-projections
    %of the point (P).
    %syntax: \tdplotsetcoord{Coordinate name without parentheses}{r}{\theta}{\phi}
    \tdplotsetcoord{P}{\rvec}{\thetavec}{\phivec}

    %draw figure contents
    %--------------------

    %draw the main coordinate system axes
    \draw[thick,->] (0,0,0) -- (-1.5,0,0)-- (1.5,0,0) node[anchor=north east]{$x$};
    \draw[thick,->] (0,0,0) -- (0,-1.5,0)--(0,1.5,0) node[anchor=north west]{$y$};
    \draw[thick,->] (0,0,-1) -- (0,0,-1.5)-- (0,0,1.5) node[anchor=south]{$z$};





    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Edited image:
[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Based on `tikz-3dplot` package definitions.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}   
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}

\begin{document}

%Angle Definitions
%-----------------

%set the plot display orientation
%syntax: \tdplotsetdisplay{\theta_d}{\phi_d}
\tdplotsetmaincoords{65}{110}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\rvec}{1}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\thetavecc}{55}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\phivecc}{35}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\thetaveccc}{39.7}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\phiveccc}{55}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=5,tdplot_main_coords,>=latex]

\shadedraw[tdplot_screen_coords,ball color = white] (0,0) circle (\rvec);
\node[tdplot_screen_coords,xshift=1cm,yshift=3mm] (0,0) {$q=-1$};

\def\h{1} 

%-----------------------
\coordinate (O) at (0,0,0);

%draw the main coordinate system axes
\draw[thick,opacity=0.5] (0,0,0) -- (1,0,0);
\draw[thick,opacity=0.5] (0,0,0) -- (0,1,0);
\draw[thick,opacity=0.5] (0,0,0) -- (0,0,1);
\draw[thick,->] (1,0,0) -- (2.3,0,0) node[anchor=north east]{$x$};
\draw[thick,->] (0,1,0) -- (0,1.5,0) node[anchor=north west]{$y$};
\draw[thick,->] (0,0,1) -- (0,0,1.5) node[anchor=south]{$z$};

% Equator 
\draw[dashed] (\rvec,0,0) arc (0:360:\rvec);
\draw[thick] (\rvec,0,0) arc (0:110:\rvec);
\draw[thick] (\rvec,0,0) arc (0:-70:\rvec);

% Flux arrows
\foreach \t in {10,20,...,340}
        \foreach \f in {180,170,...,0}
            \draw [black!60,opacity=1.0, <-, thick]
                ({sin(\f - \h)*cos(\t - \h)}, {sin(\f - \h)*sin(\t - \h)}, {cos(\f - \h)})
                -- ({(1 + 0.2*cos(90 - \f))*sin(\f - \h)*cos(\t - \h)},
                    {(1 + 0.2*cos(90 - \f))*sin(\f - \h)*sin(\t - \h)},
                    {(1 + 0.2*cos(90 - \f))*cos(\f - \h)});

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way to decrease the intensity of the arrows? Also maybe the color of the sphere?

Comment: @Shamina, your welcome. To decrease the intensity of the arrows, change the increment or decrement of  the `\foreach` loops in Flux arrows  definitions. For example  `\foreach \t in {10,30,...,340} ` and so on. For color of sphere, insert `opacitiy` key in `\shadedraw`. For example, `\shadedraw[tdplot_screen_coords,ball color = white,opacity=0.5] (0,0) circle (\rvec);`

Comment: Just one last question, what decides the length of arrows?

Comment: In flux arrows section, change the multiplier of `cos`, say  `(1 + 0.5*cos(90 - \f))`.

Comment: This is a very nice answer, +1. May I suggest to draw the thing in 3 steps? 1. arrows in the background. 2. Sphere. 3. Arrows in the foreground.

Comment: @marmot, Thank you for suggestions. By the way, I'm sure you'd give a better answer than mine.

Answer (score 3):

The following code does draw the sphere (above the axes to hide them) and the -1. It uses `tikz-3dplot` which is in TeX Live.

[image: with flux arrows]

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}

\begin{document}
    \tdplotsetmaincoords{60}{135}

    \pgfmathsetmacro{\rvec}{.8}

    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=5,tdplot_main_coords]
    \coordinate (O) at (0,0,0);

    \draw[thick,->] (-1.5,0,0)-- (1.5,0,0) node[anchor=north east]{$x$};
    \draw[thick,->] (0,-1.5,0)--(0,1.5,0) node[anchor=north west]{$y$};
    \draw[thick,->] (0,0,-1.5)-- (0,0,1.5) node[anchor=south]{$z$};

    \shade[tdplot_screen_coords,ball color = white] (0,0) circle (\rvec);

    \foreach \i in {0,20,...,360}
      \draw[tdplot_screen_coords,<-] (\i:.9*\rvec) -- (\i: 1.1*\rvec);

    \node[tdplot_screen_coords] (0,0) {$-1$};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Is there a way to get those flux arrows(pointing inside the sphere) also? Is there a way to get an equator? Also the axes to be seen but bit blur inside the sphere?

Comment: @Shamina I have added some arrows. Could you please edit your question to make the other requirements more clear (which type of blurring do you refer to and where do you want the equator to be)?

Comment: I edited my answer. I mean blurring inside the sphere